# Laravel Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I have a many to many relation in my laravel application.
The model `Competition` belongsToMany `Location` and vice versa.

Now I am trying to provide a functionality where one can add existing locations to a competition.

```
$competition    = Competition::where('id','=', $request->input('contestId'))->firstOrFail();
$locations      = $competition->locations;
$locationNames  = [];

foreach ($locations as $location) {
    $locationNames[] = $location->name;
}

if (!in_array($request->input('locationList'), $locationNames)) {
    $locationId = Location::where('name','=', $request->input('locationList'))->firstOrFail()->id;
    $competition->locations()->attach($locationId);
}
```

I need to check wheter the competition already has the location, so I store competition data inside `$competition`. Afterwards, if the location was not found, I attach the location to the competition.

The problem is the amount of queries that are running; one for the competition data, one for the location to retrieve its id, when it hasn't been found inside the competition locations, and one to store the data when attaching.

This returns an error: **"Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded"**

What is the correct way of doing so? To minimize the amount of queries needed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Location list only contains 1 location?
Some minor improvements are:
Competition::findOrFail($request->input('contestId'));
$locationNames = $competition->locations()->pluck('name')->toArray();

Comment: Yes, Its the value that was selected within a form select.

Comment: Do you know on wich line the code gets a timeout?

Comment: No, the Laravel error didn't tell me on which line it timed out. I did found a solution tho, I've posted it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For some reason, the error didn't appear **when I closed my Sqlite DB browser desktop program**. Yet this is very strange, since I had the sqlite db browser app open since the beginning of my app creation.

Answer (score 5):

Your query is seems to be ok, but foreach loop i think it's not ok so  update code like this:

```
$competition = Competition::where('id','=', $request->input('contestId'))->firstOrFail();

if($locationId = Location::where('name','=', $request->input('locationList'))->first()){
      $competition->locations()->attach($locationId->id);
}
```

> If location is there then added otherwise not added

Add line  in `public/index.php` file [function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

```
set_time_limit($seconds);
```

otherwise increase the `max_execution_time` in `php.ini` and restart server

Comment: But is this the best way to retrieve the data? Because if the timeout is due to the amount of queries being executed, it might not be smart to just increase the time limit, right?

Comment: @Regentix i think foreach loop it is not ok so `remove loop` and use `mysql query` i updated my answer

Comment: The foreach loop checks if the result of `$competition->locations` has the `$request->input('locationList')` value. If I would implement your code, I would attach the location **if the location doesn't exist**, but thats not what I want to check, because I already know it does.

Answer (score 2):

Just clear All Cache

**step:1** Go your project directory and open command prompt

**step:2** write command in command prompt  **php artisan optimize:clear**

Then check your problem is solved...